# Spring autowire is giving nullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, autowired

This is the controller which calls thread 'TestRunner'.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addCustomerPage() throws Exception{
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("customer/add-customer-form");

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        TestRunner runner = new TestRunner(a, b, c); 
        Thread t = new Thread(runner);
        t.start();
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

This is my thread which calls service HomeService. This service is autowired but still I getting null pointer exception when I call `homeService.testMeth(a,b,c);`

```
@Controller
public class TestRunner implements Runnable{

    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    @Autowired
    private HomeService homeService;



    public TestRunner() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public TestRunner(A a, B b, C c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        homeService.testMeth(a,b,c);
    }

}
```

This is service class.

```
@Service
public class HomeService {

    public void testMeth(A a, B b, C c){
        System.out.println("inside....");
    }
}
```

Is this because of I am creating 'TestRunner' object with 'new' ?

Comment: _Is this because of I am creating 'TestRunner' object with 'new' ?_ Yes. Why arent you letting Spring create the controller?

Comment: like autowiring TestRunner inside HomeController ? but I want to pass parameters to TestRunner constructor.

Comment: The easiest way to solve that is to make TestRunner *create* and return a Runnable, from a, b and c passed as arguments to a method, rather than TestRunner *being* a Runnable. And it shouldn't be annotated with `@Controller` since it's not a controller at all. Use `@Component` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because of I am creating 'TestRunner' object with 'new' ?

Yes, It is because of this you get NullpointerExceptoin.

To fix the issue change the following:

1. Mark the following three classes A, B, C as component - if not
   already done. Ensure the package is in component scan path:

   @Component
   public class A {

   @Component
   public class B {

   @Component
   public class C {
2. Then Autowire the A, B, C instances in TestRunner. Also change the annotation of TestRunner to @Component

   @Component
   public class TestRunner implements Runnable{
       @Autowired
       private A a;

   ```
   @Autowired
   private B b;

   @Autowired
   private C c;
   ```
3. In HomeRunner create an instance field for TestRunner and autowire it. Remove the instansiation code with new operator for TestRunner.

Comment: I got your point but A,B,C are POJOs. I am settings its fields in HomeController & passing those objects in TestRunner. How will I be able to pass these objects to TestRunner?